# How to get Access-Token from paypal profile

Tags: php, api, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to get an access Access-Token from PayPal to use in PayPal Single Payout Developer API.

But how do I get the access token from this credential?

```
$client_id = 'AdXsXfAl9EnbcpQ0809yD7hjZ8fQL5WouTkarNlWq1NhAD1oFBbAy66PDpVo1xTjMF-wAJTqJ76jPFWR';  //DUMMY

$secret = 'EB_DLdxEo5w8bj-jzY1N0RBcIj4RXqgLEKhk-BFJvjvFaMwj9O86ePVGzMZGO6uvCLBaNxbq2P-xB3FJ';  //DUMMY
```

Comment: I would recommend not publishing credentials online.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$client_id = 'AdXsXfAl9EnbcpQ0809yD7hjZ8fQL5WouTkarNlWq1NhAD1oFBbAy66PDpVo1xTjMF-wAJTqJ76jPFWR';  //DUMMY
$secret = 'EB_DLdxEo5w8bj-jzY1N0RBcIj4RXqgLEKhk-BFJvjvFaMwj9O86ePVGzMZGO6uvCLBaNxbq2P-xB3FJ';  //DUMMY

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");  //DUMMY
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");  //LIVE
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $client_id . ":" . $secret);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
$headers[] = "Accept-Language: en_US";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
pr(json_decode($result)->access_token);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Beware disabling certificate verification (`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`) is very bad security practice!!